# usps-webtools authentication fails

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a nodejs javascript test program as follows:

```js
const USPS = require('usps-webtools');

const usps = new USPS({
    server: 'https://production.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPI.dll',
    userId: 'user:passwd',
    ttl: 10000 //TTL in milliseconds for request
    });
usps.verify({
    street1: '1234 Some Lane',
    city: 'AnyTown',
    state: 'MI',
    zip: '12345'
    }, function(err, address){
      console.log(err)
      console.log(address);
      });
```

It always returns with:

> Authorization failure. Perhaps username and/or password is incorrect.

> USPSCOM::DoAuth

But I can go to usps.gov and login with the same account name and password.
How does it want me to pass the username and password to it?

Answer (score 0):

I just tested your code and the problem appears to be the value you are passing for the userId

Instead of passing your username and password in this format
userId: 'user:passwd',

Set the userId equal to **your WebTools username only.**

Here is a screenshot of the email you'll receive once you register at the USPS website.

[image]

The docs for the USPS APIs aren't great, so we created some modern ones using Redocly at https://www.uspsweb.tools and create a public postman collection for developers to explore the APIs at https://www.postman.com/lobteam/workspace/usps-web-tools-public-workspace/overview

Best of Luck!

Comment: Removing the ":password" produces the same results.  Authorization failure.

Comment: Hi @DanielBidwell - are you setting the  userId value to the username you received from the USPS?  

You can register here to get your username & password
https://www.usps.com/business/web-tools-apis/

This is the NPM package I used with the code above
https://www.npmjs.com/package/usps-webtools